# Which scheduling algorithm is used for threads within a process

Tags: multithreading

In an intervew I was asked this question:

> What is the thread scheduling algorithm like round robin and FCFS is process scheduling algorithm,
>   in similar way what is thread scheduling algorithm.

I told there is not specific order that the threads within a process are going to execute that's why the problem of race condition occurred.

It all depends on processor that will randomly choose any thread to execute it.

But interviewer didn't seem satisfied.

Any help?

Thank you

Comment: In which conditions? I mean... is a question about Java, C++? Which os?? If is Java... which Virtual Machine?

Comment: it was on c++  and linux os thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603341/what-scheduling-algorithms-does-linux-kernel-use ?

Comment: I note that you haven't taken the time to mark any of the answers to your previous questions as "accepted". People might be more inclined to help you out if they saw their efforts were appreciated.

Comment: okay.. sure i will not miss from next time onwards..

Comment: You can do it retrospectively too...