# How to select linux process scheduler in menuconfig while kernel compilation

Tags: linux, process, compilation, kernel, scheduler

I need to select O(1) process scheduler in linux kernel!
but i can't find where to select it in menuconfig window.
how to change from O(1) to CFS and vise versa?

edit:
please attention to PROCESS SCHEDULER. I do not mean I/O SCHEDULER.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1603341/what-scheduling-algorithms-does-linux-kernel-use) StackOverflow thread answers a similar question:

According to the above changing the scheduler type is done dynamically at runtime.

TL;DR

```
cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
```

to check what is running

```
sudo bash -c 'echo deadline > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler'
```

to change.

Excuse me if you meant compiling the options into the "from scratch" kernel build. In that case it is in the 2.6.15-rc4 configuration it is under:
[Block layer --->
IO Schedulers --->](http://how-to.wikia.com/wiki/Guide_to_configuring_the_linux_kernel/Block_layer/IO_Schedulers)

**Edit**
After realizing I misread the question and referenced the IO scheduler rather than the Process Scheduler:

The CFS is the only process scheduler in the new kernels. It is possible to play with its attributes to make it more "real time" with the `sched` command

Comment: I mean **PROCESS SCEDULER**. you referenced I/O SCHEDULER. these are different :-)

Comment: There is only one proc sched in linux, and currently it is CFS. You could change its attributes though with "sched"